# Boost Graph Library - Push vector into edge property

Tags: c++, boost

I was wondering if it is possible to set a property for an edge by pushing a value in. An example is shown below.

```
struct Edge {

    //boundary length
    int length = 0;

    //boundary coordinates
    vector<cv::Point> boundary;

    //pointer to heap
    boost::heap::fibonacci_heap<rnn, boost::heap::compare<compare_nn>>::handle_type heap_pointer;

    Edge(float length = 0) : length (length ) {}
};

//i'd like to push in point into vector<cv::Point> boundary
boost::put(&Edge::boundary, g, boost::edge(0, 1, g), cv::Point(2,2));
```

I could **get** the vector property, **push** a point in before I **put** it back into the Edge but it seems highly in-efficient. I was hoping someone could give me a suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even simpler:

```
auto& boundary = boost::get(&Edge::boundary, g, boost::edge(0, 1, g));
boundary.emplace_back(2,2);
```

The crux is to take a *reference* to the vector instead of copying it.

Of course you can spell it out as `push_back(cv::Point(2,2))` if your standard library doesn't support `emplace_back` yet.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand properly your question, but it seems that here might be helpul simple struct method:

```
struct Edge {
  // your stuff here
  void push(cv::Point& point) {
    boundary.push_back(point);
  }
};
```